# NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application

Tags: hibernate, jpa, caching, spring-boot, jhipster

I am getting the below error:

> Second-level cache is used in the application, but property
>   hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either
>   disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the
>   hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second
>   level cache provider

A similar question was asked but we seem to have different issues. First I was having a issue with the `"hibernate.connection.url"` and I am pretty sure I resolved that but I cannot get past the above error.

I generated this project with jHipster and created a persistence.xml file and placed it under `resources`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <!-- h2 -->

    <persistence-unit name="h2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:./drew" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="sa" />
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

In my .h2.server.properties I have:

```
#H2 Server Properties
0=JHipster H2 (Memory)|org.h2.Driver|jdbc\:h2\:mem\:drew|drew
webAllowOthers=true
webPort=8082
webSSL=false
```

All my entities at annotated with:

`@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)`

Comment: JHipster does not need a persistence.xml, so I don't know what you're trying to do.  In JHipster projects, cache configuration is achieved through CacheConfiguration class, cache regions are created there.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I am using H2 and need to test my JPA query's so I do need one. I am doing complex queries and need to test them in Intellij.

Comment: Have you tried to put persistence.xml in test resources to avoid conflicting with JHipster/Spring Boot configuration when running your app?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I just did and left the file as is and got the following `Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.`

Comment: @GaëlMarziou any suggestions, I am stuck...

Comment: Sorry, you're too far from standard JHipster configuration and I don't have IntelliJ Ultimate to test this feature. I simply use JUnit to test my queries. Did you ask Jetbrains? Maybe you could disable spring boot autoconfiguration for JPA and cache and do all manually.

Comment: Do you get this when trying to execute the query in IntelliJ IDEA JPA/Hibernate console? Then please follow [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166811) in IntelliJ IDEA tracker.

Comment: @Andrey how can I get past the bug. I wrote intellij and they responded with the link you provided. This is happening in the H2 and JPA console.